# Iterating through a dataframe with condition from a column and a list in pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have my dataframe like the one defined below:

I have a list and the new dataframe should start with the first row of the old df. For eg it should take the Turn[0] = 260 and then compare it with the list. Here 284 is the first value which is greater than the first value i.e 260. If it is greater then it should look for the flag, if the flag is 1 then append that row. So in the new dataframe 284 with flag 0 is omitted. Then the new value for comparison should be 284 rather than 260 and it should do the same stated as above. In the old df after 290 it is 1 therefore the list should iterate from the first and check if 1 has a flag 1 then append.

Hope it is clear now

```
| Turn     | Flag     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 260      | 0        |
| 265      | 0        |
| 284      | 0        |
| 284      | 0        |                    
| 284      | 1        |
| 285      | 0        |
| 290      | 1        |
| 290      | 0        |
| 1        | 1        |

and I have a list like [1,45,56,98,284,290]. Now I want a new df like :

| Turn     | Flag     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 260      | 0        |
| 265      | 0        |
| 284      | 1        |
| 285      | 0        |                    
| 290      | 1        |
| 1        | 1        |
```

The df has values which are not in the list and they can be omitted. Just start from the first row append the turn which is greater than the turn[0] and equal to the value in lis with Flag 1(In this eg after 260, 284 is the value greater and have a flag 1). Then take the last appended value which is 284 as the starting for the next comparison and the code should get 290 as it is greater and have flag 1.

Comment: why rows with `0` flag occur in the result (while you wanted to omit them)?

Comment: Other values of Turn which are not in the list should also be there in the result. If you take a close look the result have flag 0 for only the values which are not in the list.